# numpy.matmul is giving an error but AT (@) is not

Tags: numpy

In the below screenshot, numpy.matmul is complaining about something on line 12, but I am not sure what. But the @ operator works on line 11. This snippet is part of a jupyter notebook, but I printed out the types and shapes of the arrays we're multiplying. Could someone advise as to what is going on here with matmul?

[image]

Comment: @QuangHoang I just converted the `y_train` to a numpy array and I still get the same error

Comment: Did you convert the `x_train_0` to numpy array?

Comment: @QuangHoang Yes. That was already a numpy array in the original post.

Comment: @QuangHoang I got it working now. I'm a bit new to jupyter notebook and it seems it wasn't updating some changes in earlier lines of the code.